# NodeJS class always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, instance

I am trying to pass values ​​from one class to another js file, but on all attempts it always returns me undefined.
this is my stage

**config.js**

```
class Token {
  _token = '';

  constructor(token) {
    this._token = token;
  }

  get getToken() {
    return this._token;
  }
}

class Url {
  get getUrl() {
    return 'https://api.com';
  }
}

exports.token = Token;
exports.url = Url;
```

instance.js

```
const config = require('./config');

let tkn = new config.token();
console.log('tkn', tkn.getToken);
console.log('TKN', config.token.getToken);

let url = new config.url();
console.log('URL', config.url.getUrl);
console.log('url', tkn.getUrl);
```

Comment: What returns undefined and at which line? (Note that for `token` you create the instance without parameter `new config.token();` so it's normal that it would return `undefined`)

Comment: both in the instance to the class as well as in the direct call, both return undefined, 
On the other hand, the idea of ​​using getters came from this same site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your instance.js file will be similar to this

```
const config = require('./config');
config.url.getUrl();
```

and config.js file

```
class Token {
        _token = '';

        constructor(token) {
          this._token = _token;
        }

        static getToken() {

          return this._token;

        }
      }

      class Url {
        static getUrl() {
          //return 'https://api.com';
          console.log("something")
        }
      }

      exports.token = Token;
      exports.url = Url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct usage of your script would be

```
const config = require('./config');

let tkn = new config.token('value');
//                         ^^^^^^^^
console.log('tkn', tkn.getToken); // value

let url = new config.url();
console.log('url', url.getUrl); // https://api.com
//                 ^^^
```

The getter properties you defined are not static, you cannot access them on `config.token` or `config.url`.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've commented the issues:

```
const config = require('./config');

let tkn = new config.token(); // Token constructor expects an argument.
console.log('tkn', tkn.getToken); // This is correct and will work provided the constructor argument.
console.log('TKN', config.token.getToken); // You must instantiate the token and use the instance.

let url = new config.url();
console.log('URL', config.url.getUrl); // Same as with the token. It must be instantiated and getUrl accessed through that instance.
console.log('url', tkn.getUrl); // Here you're trying to call getUrl of the Token class but it doesn't exist.
```

Fixed version

```
const config = require('./config');

let tkn = new config.token("token");
console.log('tkn', tkn.getToken);

let url = new config.url();
console.log('URL', url.getUrl);
```